How to use Groq Api in Java for an Android App (Android Studio)?
I have already used groq api in python, to inference with LLMs. Now I wonder wether it would be possible to do the same with Java. I have already found this curl script. Can I use it in an Android App? Or would there be an better way to do it?
curl https://api.groq.com/openai/v1/chat/completions -s \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $GROQ_API_KEY" \
-d '{
"model": "llama3-8b-8192",
"messages": [{
    "role": "user",
    "content": "Explain the importance of fast language models"
}]
}'

Thanks in advance!


I have already found this curl script. Can I use it in an Android App?

Not directly, insofar as curl is a command-line program, and we do not use those very often from within a Java/Kotlin program.

Or would there be an better way to do it?

The most popular options for making REST-style Web API calls like this in Android apps are OkHttp with or without Retrofit. For example, the former openai-java project used Retrofit with OkHttp.
